# Unable to run Performance Profiler on Android Emulator deployment of MAUI app using Visual Studio 2022

Tags: android, visual-studio, maui, profiler

My app is hanging when rendering a particular View in my app in an Android emulator. It also occasionally crashes. To help identify where it's crashing and to tune its performance overall, I'm trying to run the Performance Profiler from within Visual Studio 2022 (version 17.5.3).

I can't get the profiler tools to work on my app. So, I figured I'd try to run it on the simple MAUI demo app from Microsoft, "RadioButtonDemos". Sure enough, I get the same errors with the demo app.

When I try to run the profiler immediately after a build, I get this error message:

```
08:39:27:604    'RadioButtonDemos' failed to launch
08:39:27:604    
08:39:27:604    Exception of type 'Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.Diagnostics.CollectionStartFailedHubException' was thrown.
```

Even though the message says, "failed to launch", the app actually did launch. It's as if the profiler isn't able to find the running process.

If I try to run the profiler again, I get:

```
08:39:49:376    'RadioButtonDemos' failed to launch
08:39:49:376    
08:39:49:376    Unable to obtain package full name from target 'RadioButtonDemos'.
```

In my project profile, the "Developer instrumentation" option for "Debug" is checked. I get the same error message when I try to run the "Application Profiler", "Events Viewer" or "CPU Usage" profiler tools. I manually started the "Visual Studio Standard Collector Service 150"...no joy. I tried on both Debug and Release builds.

I read through all the Visual Studio profiler documentation which gave me no path to success.

Can the profiler actually be used for a process running in the emulator? It's the first time I've tried it.

Is anyone else running the performance profiler tools in VS 2022 for an Android emulator deployment with success?

Any leads for getting this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using emulators for performance testing is not a good idea as the results may be totally different from a real device. The emulatorsprovided by Android Studio are pretty good but in the end there is still a large gap to a real device.

Comment: I completely agree with you regarding performance tuning. However, I’m hopeful it can help me identify why the app is hanging. If I stop the app when it’s hanging, VS always says it’s in external code.

Comment: Did you used the third party Performance Profiler? And you can refer to the [wiki on the github about Profiling .NET MAUI Apps](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Profiling-.NET-MAUI-Apps).